# Replace text followed by @ using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to create a JavaScript function which replace the word followed by @

Example:

```
              var sample = "Hello @Jon how are you";
              var result  = myfunction(sample);
              // result should be like "Hello xxxxxx how are you"
```

Here @ symbol also need to be replaced.

Comment: how many `xxxx` should be der

Comment: `result = sample.replace(/@\w+/, 'xxxxx');`

Comment: @vks that is our wish

Comment: @anubhava yes xxxx will vary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@\S+
```

Try this.Replace by `xxx`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/38

```
var re = /@\S+/gm;
var str = 'Hello @Jon how are you';
var subst = 'x';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex,

```
@(\w+)
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jM7nM5/1)